# Replace PVC valve cemented on a water line

Tags: pipe, valve, pvc, cpvc, pipe-fitting

I have a filtering system with a bypass and one of the valves was badly installed and it also leaks through the handle gasket. The valve is in a system that looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The encircled area is where the problematic valve is. As you can see, it would be very hard to cut the line and add a new valve, because I cannot bend the main line too much. The valve is cemented to the pipe and threaded to the filter (the blue rectangle), but connected to the main line with a cemented T-shape fitting. In other words, I cannot just unscrew it, as it is permanent. What options do I have in this situation, without needing to do the entire system?

Comment: One option is build a whole new manifold, replacing pretty much everything you drew there.

Comment: Yeah… I was afraid of that, but aren’t there really no other solutions? I was thinking that cutting the line, remove the valve, add a new one and add some sort of ring around the cut, but I can’t find anything. Maybe because I don’t know how to search? Or maybe it is nonexistent?

Comment: You can cut at the valve and even use heat to disassemble and reuse the fittings but couplings would be needed and freeman would be easier. Couplings or new pipe and some new pipe will be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually these fittings are glued in place, and failures mean replumbing.

Since you don't have a lot of space to work with on that short horizontal run, make space like this:

- Cut the pipe coming out of the T and put a cap on it (Yellow Square)
- Cut the supply pipe and put in a new T and an elbow (Red lines)
- Put a new valve in, oriented for vertical flow (Green rectangle)
- Finish the plumbing into the filter system with more straight pipe and another elbow (other red lines)

[image: crude drawing of depiction above]

Should there ever be another failure, you should have a little more pipe to work with. You could, of course, use compression fittings and screw all this together if you really wanted to, but gluing is the standard here.

Comment: You beat me two it , probably a half dozen ways all of them require a little work even using the heat method to re use the fittings couplings would be needed to repair cuts that is what I was thinking but yours takes less experience probably a better diy method.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. Seems like the best. Two questions, though. 1. Won’t adding two extra bends affect the pressure drop? And 2. Is cementing better than compression in this case?

Comment: The flow rate will be impacted by elbows, but, unless your city/well pressure is _really_ low, you'll never notice.

Comment: I would glue these fittings and deal with cutting the thing apart in another 20 or 30 years to replace another valve if necessary. TBH, I'm not sure if you can actually find compression fittings for 1" (or so) PVC pipe. You can probably find screw on fittings and use those if you prefer. It'll probably cost more because you'll have to buy threaded fittings and glue those on and you'll need a union somewhere to make the final connection where you have to screw one thing in on both ends. A union fitting has a standard CW thread on one end and a CCW thread on the other to allow this.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for your advice. I guess that’s what I’ll do. Should there be pressure loss, I would just try to redo everything.

Comment: There is a lot of bend on the bypass horizontal length, I don't see why you can just cut out the top far right 90, cut somewhere on the in riser and just redo exactly as it was

Comment: There are plenty of options, @FreshCodemonger. That was the first that popped into my head.

Comment: If you are _really_ worried about pressure loss, the red tee-piece can be a 45-degree tee (eg https://www.pipestock.com/pvc/pvc-pipe-fittings-inch/tee-45), and then the elbow under the green valve can be a 45-degree elbow.  Similarly the red elbow above the value can be a short radius 90-degree bend (eg https://www.pipestock.com/pvc/pvc-pipe-fittings-inch/short-radius-bend-90).  That should be as good as the original - if not better.

Comment: "short radius 90-degree bend" did you mean "long radius", @MartinBonnersupportsMonica? I would think that a longer radius would make for a smoother flow with less restriction...

Comment: @FreeMan I was copying the title from the linked web page.  Longer would be better, but the gain from an increase beyond that would be small.

Answer (score 2):

cut the pipe to the right of the bad valve, flex the pipe sideways parallel with the cut (eg into the photo)  then unscrew the bad valve and pipe stub from the filter block.

install half a pipe union on the cut pipe end. Assemble a new valve and pipe stub to the other half of the union screw it in, (un)flex the pipe back and close the union.

All joints to be sealed with pipe cement or thread tape as appropriate (except closing the union).

You can probably cut the pipe stub off the bad valve and reuse that, but a new piece may be needed to go between the union and the valve.